# Java Collection that prints value in small brackets and white space separated?

Tags: java

How to create a generic java collection that prints the value like this:
(with small brackets and without comma)

```
SomeGenericCollection someGenericCollectionInstance = new SomeGenericColllection();

someGenericCollectionInstance.add("A");
someGenericCollectionInstance.add("B");

System.out.println(someGenericCollectionInstance);
```

The expected output is:

("A" "B")

*Other Scenario:*

```
SomeGenericCollection someGenericCollectionInstance = new SomeGenericColllection();

someGenericCollectionInstance.add(1);
someGenericCollectionInstance.add(2);

System.out.println(someGenericCollectionInstance);
```

(1 2)

Comment: You just need to override the toString() method.

Comment: Have a look at [Google's Guava Joiner](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained) or use a simple `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you just want to override the `AbstractCollection`'s `toString` method.
Like this :

```
public abstract class MyCollection<E> extends AbstractCollection<E> {

@Override
public String toString() {
    Iterator<E> it = iterator();
    if (! it.hasNext())
        return "()";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('(');
    for (;;) {
        E e = it.next();
        sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
        if (! it.hasNext())
            return sb.append(')').toString();
        sb.append(' ');
    }
}
```

}

Comment: hi, there, could you please tell me the meaning of this line:  `sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);`

Comment: hello @Ruizhi , the toString method in my answer was actually pasted from `AbstractCollection`'s source (it is the original method). But to explain :  `e == this ? "foo" : "bar"` is a ternary operator which returns `"foo"` if `e == this` is true, and `"bar"` otherwise. Now, why did they do that ? Because, if the collection contains itself (the element `e` is `this`), calling `e.toString()` would result in infinite recursion. Thus, we replace it by `"this Collection"`. so that a `List<Object>` containing the int `1` and itself (`list.add(list);`) will get printed as `"[1,(this Collection)]"`.

Answer (score 1):

Just provide your own Implementation of the interface. Say you copy the content of ArrayList class and - in addition - you override the toString() method with the format you want.